# ERROR: Element 'Return': No matching global declaration available for the validation root

Tags: xml, xsd

I am trying to validate xml file with xsd file for filing T2202 TAX SLIP for canada revenue agency

Below is my xml file which can be slightly changed for it to validate with xsd schema file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Return>
    <T2202>
        <T2202Slip>
            <SlipReportTypeCode>O</SlipReportTypeCode>
            <FilerAccountNumber>000000000RZ0000</FilerAccountNumber>
            <PostSecondaryEducationalSchoolProgramName>Webdevelopment</PostSecondaryEducationalSchoolProgramName>
            <PostSecondaryEducationalSchoolTypeCode>1</PostSecondaryEducationalSchoolTypeCode>
            <FlyingSchoolClubCourseTypeCode>1</FlyingSchoolClubCourseTypeCode>
            <StudentName>
                <FamilyName>Jacob</FamilyName>
                <GivenName>peter</GivenName>
                <NameInitialText>k</NameInitialText>
            </StudentName>
            <SocialInsuranceNumber>000000000</SocialInsuranceNumber>
            <StudentNumber>501058988</StudentNumber>
            <StudentAddress>
                <AddressLine1Text>202-2526 LAKEVIEW</AddressLine1Text>
                <AddressLine2Text>CRES</AddressLine2Text>
                <CityName>ABBOTSFORD</CityName>
                <ProvinceStateCode>BC</ProvinceStateCode>
                <CountryCode>CAN</CountryCode>
                <PostalZipCode>V2W3A9</PostalZipCode>
            </StudentAddress>
            <SchoolSession>
                <StartYearMonth>1901</StartYearMonth>
                <EndYearMonth>1909</EndYearMonth>
                <EligibleTuitionFeeAmount>153.64</EligibleTuitionFeeAmount>
                <PartTimeStudentMonthCount>9</PartTimeStudentMonthCount>
                <FullTimeStudentMonthCount>0</FullTimeStudentMonthCount>
            </SchoolSession>
            <TotalEligibleTuitionFeeAmount>0</TotalEligibleTuitionFeeAmount>
            <TotalPartTimeStudentMonthCount>0</TotalPartTimeStudentMonthCount>
            <TotalFullTimeStudentMonthCount>0</TotalFullTimeStudentMonthCount>
        </T2202Slip>
        <T2202Summary>
            <FilerAccountNumber>000000000RZ0000</FilerAccountNumber>
            <SummaryReportTypeCode>O</SummaryReportTypeCode>
            <TaxationYear>2019</TaxationYear>
            <TotalSlipCount>1</TotalSlipCount>
            <PostSecondaryEducationalInstitutionName>
                <NameLine1Text>CAREER COLLEGE</NameLine1Text>
            </PostSecondaryEducationalInstitutionName>
            <PostSecondaryEducationalInstitutionMailingAddress>
                <CityName>ABBOTSFORD</CityName>
                <ProvinceStateCode>BC</ProvinceStateCode>
                <CountryCode>CAN</CountryCode>
                <PostalZipCode>V2W3A9</PostalZipCode>
            </PostSecondaryEducationalInstitutionMailingAddress>
            <ContactInformation>
                <ContactName>JOHN</ContactName>
                <ContactAreaCode>604</ContactAreaCode>
                <ContactPhoneNumber>720-4037</ContactPhoneNumber>
                <ContactExtensionNumber>6789</ContactExtensionNumber>
            </ContactInformation>
            <TotalEligibleTuitionFeeAmount>153.64</TotalEligibleTuitionFeeAmount>
        </T2202Summary>
    </T2202>
</Return>
```

Please find below my xsd schema file which is from the government website.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<!--
Description T2202 Return Complex and Element Types
Last updated    May 2019
Version#:   1.19 (version #.yy)
-->

<xsd:schema xmlns:sdt="http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/xmlns/sdt/2-2-0" 
    xmlns:ccms="http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/xmlns/ccms/1-0-0" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:import namespace="http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/xmlns/sdt/2-2-0" schemaLocation="standarddatatypes.xsd"/>
    <xsd:import namespace="http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/xmlns/ccms/1-0-0" schemaLocation="cracommonstructures.xsd"/>
    <xsd:include schemaLocation="lemmcommontypes.xsd"/>

    <xsd:complexType name="T2202SlipType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element ref="SlipReportTypeCode"/>
            <xsd:element name="FilerAccountNumber" type="BNRZType"/>
            <xsd:element name="PostSecondaryEducationalSchoolProgramName" type="Length1to30TextType"/>

            <!-- School type code:
                1. University
                2. College
                3. Other education institution providing courses at a post-secondary school level
                4. Certified by the Minister of Employment and Social Development Canada
                5. Flying school or club
            -->
            <xsd:element name="PostSecondaryEducationalSchoolTypeCode" type="OneToFiveCodeType"/>

            <!-- Flying school or club course type code. Must have a value if School type code is 5,
                 should be blank if school type code is 1-4. Valid values:
                1. Private pilots license
                2. Commercial pilots licence
                3. Civil flying instructor rating
                4. Helicopter category rating
                5. Instrument rating
                6. Other
            -->
            <xsd:element name="FlyingSchoolClubCourseTypeCode" type="OneToSixCodeType" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="StudentName" type="IndividualNameType"/>
            <xsd:element name="SocialInsuranceNumber" type="ccms:SINType"/>
            <xsd:element name="StudentNumber" type="Length1to20TextType" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="StudentAddress" type="RequiredLine1AddressType"/>
            <xsd:element name="SchoolSession" type="SchoolSessionType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="4"/>
            <xsd:element name="TotalEligibleTuitionFeeAmount" type="Decimal13AmountType" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="TotalPartTimeStudentMonthCount" type="ZeroToTwelveCountType"/>
            <xsd:element name="TotalFullTimeStudentMonthCount" type="ZeroToTwelveCountType"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="SchoolSessionType">
        <xsd:all>
            <xsd:element name="StartYearMonth" type="YYMMType"/>
            <xsd:element name="EndYearMonth" type="YYMMType"/>
            <xsd:element name="EligibleTuitionFeeAmount" type="Decimal11AmountType" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="PartTimeStudentMonthCount" type="ZeroToTwelveCountType"/>
            <xsd:element name="FullTimeStudentMonthCount" type="ZeroToTwelveCountType"/>
        </xsd:all>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="T2202SummaryType">
        <xsd:all>
            <xsd:element name="FilerAccountNumber" type="BNRZType"/>
            <xsd:element ref="SummaryReportTypeCode"/>
            <xsd:element name="FilerAmendmentNote" type="Length1to1309TextType" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element ref="TaxationYear"/>
            <xsd:element ref="TotalSlipCount"/>
            <xsd:element name="PostSecondaryEducationalInstitutionName" type="ThreeLinedLength30NameType"/>
            <xsd:element name="PostSecondaryEducationalInstitutionMailingAddress" type="RequiredLine1AddressType"/>
            <xsd:element name="ContactInformation" type="ContactType3" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="TotalEligibleTuitionFeeAmount" type="Decimal15AmountType"/>
        </xsd:all>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

I need to validate the xml file.Slight changes can be made to xml file. I am getting the error below

> ERROR: Element 'Return': No matching global declaration available for the validation root

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your example is missing the `xsd:import`files and the `xsd:include` files. Hence it's not a complete [mcve] and thus,probably unanswerable.

Comment: xsd:import files containing files which are kept secure by the goverment.The public will not be able to view them. I have created the xml file myself based on the specifications from goverment. [link]https://www.canada.ca/en/revenue-agency/services/e-services/filing-information-returns-electronically-t4-t5-other-types-returns-overview/upcoming-year-t619/t2202.html

Comment: Well, if the gov doesn't provide the files `standarddatatypes.xsd`, `cracommonstructures.xsd`  and `lemmcommontypes.xsd`, you (and nobody else, except for the gov) can validate the XML files. These files are _absolutely neccessary_ to validate the corresponding XML files, because they contain the types of the elements and attributes.

Comment: I have lemmcommontypes.xsd at [link]https://gofile.io/?c=HZkFhg. But the standarddatatypes.xsd, cracommonstructures.xsd are protected. I have contacted technical people of CRA but they won't be able to provide those files. And according to them we should be able to do the validation with parsers available in the internet.

Comment: They probably lie or are incompetent (or both). Without all of the used types you _cannot validate_ an XML files against an XSD. There is also _no need at all_ to keep this data classified, because this data assures the functioning of the interfaces and is ***not security relevant*** at all.

Comment: With the file from your link, the amount of errors got reduced. But I still get the (expectable)  error `lemmcommontypes.xsd:17:107: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'standarddatatypes.xsd'`.

Comment: [link]https://www.canada.ca/en/revenue-agency/services/e-services/filing-information-returns-electronically-t4-t5-other-types-returns-overview/filing-information-returns-electronically-t4-t5-other-types-returns-file.html  - here you can find  xmlschm1-20-5.zip under step 2 from where I got the xsd schema mentioned in the question(t2202.xsd) and lemmcommontypes.xsd . Also If you go through the steps you will see that they are not giving much information.

Comment: Here is the link to all XSDs: https://www.canada.ca/content/dam/cra-arc/serv-info/eservices/xmlschm1-20-5.zip

Comment: This is good. Now I can process the XML and try to debug its XSD. It is not sure that I will succeed, but I give it a try (It will take some time - it's 1AM here).

Comment: Oh I am sorry I didnot notice cracommonstructures.xsd andstandarddatatypes.xsd in that folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I debugged the set of your XSDs and finally isolated the crucial errors:

1. So either add the `minOccurs="0"` attribute to the following element in your `lemmcommontypes.xsd` like

   ```
   <xsd:element ref="AddressLine1Text" minOccurs="0" /> <!-- Added by edit -->
   ```

   which is probably not possible, because you cannot change the XSD.
2. Or, otherwise, add the following element as part of your XML

   ```
   <PostSecondaryEducationalInstitutionMailingAddress>
       <AddressLine1Text>WHATEVER!!!</AddressLine1Text>   <!-- Added by edit -->
       <CityName>ABBOTSFORD</CityName>
       <ProvinceStateCode>BC</ProvinceStateCode>
       <CountryCode>CAN</CountryCode>
       <PostalZipCode>V2W3A9</PostalZipCode>
   </PostSecondaryEducationalInstitutionMailingAddress>
   ```
3. Also, change the definition of `Decimal13AmountType` in `lemmcommontypes.xsd` to

   ```
   <xsd:simpleType name="Decimal13AmountType">
       <xsd:restriction base="sdt:AmountType">
           <xsd:totalDigits value="13"></xsd:totalDigits>
           <xsd:pattern value="[+]?\d{0,11}(\.\d{2})?"/>
           <xsd:minInclusive value="0"/>
       </xsd:restriction>
   </xsd:simpleType>
   ```

   which is probably not possible, because you cannot change the XSD.
4. Or, if you cannot do this, change the value(s) `TotalEligibleTuitionFeeAmount` from `0` to `0.00` to make the RegEx match.

to make the XML match your XSD set.

---

In both cases you have to add the following definitions to the above XSD file (which are copied from `frms.xsd`):

```
<xsd:complexType name="T2202ReturnType">   <!-- From frms.xsd -->
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="T2202Slip" type="T2202SlipType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xsd:element name="T2202Summary" type="T2202SummaryType"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="ReturnChoiceType">  <!-- From frms.xsd -->
    <xsd:choice>
        <xsd:element name="T2202" type="T2202ReturnType" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xsd:choice>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:element name="Return" type="ReturnChoiceType"/>
```

to make the above XML match.
Now the XML should validate.

Comment: Thanks for your time.XML is valid now by adding this code.But is there something I can add to xml file instead of changing xsd file? This is because while filing tax we need to use the proper xml. Changing the xsd is not an option.

Comment: As I wrote in the above answer: options 1 and 3 are changing the XSD and options 2 and 4 are changing the XML. So if you cannot change the XSD, use the options 2 and 4. That means adding the line `<AddressLine1Text>WHATEVER!!!</AddressLine1Text>` and changing `0` to `0.00` in your XML. Then add the definitions mentioned in the last part of the answer (after the list) to your XSD.

Comment: I made changes to xml. But I am talking about  "add the definitions mentioned in the last part of the answer (after the list) to your XSD" . This is kind of changing the xsd file right?

Comment: I had to add the last part (which I simply copied from the `frms.xsd` file) to make the whole situation you described in your question work. In a complete scenario you probably have `frms.xsd` included and hence the addition would not be neccessary. But to make this answer complete, it was. This is why I referred to the MCVE: to make the MCVE work, the last part has to be added.

Comment: "To validate your file, check both the format and content of an .xml file against our schema files using a validating parser." - I hope adding code from one file to another is fine.

Comment: Good answer, +1 from my side!

Comment: The XSD files don't need modifications. The XML is wrong. <Return> is only one component of the final file that needs to be uploaded to the CRA. See https://www.canada.ca/en/revenue-agency/services/e-services/filing-information-returns-electronically-t4-t5-other-types-returns-overview/upcoming-year-t619.html.

Comment: @Dave: Did you even read my answer? I offered two possible solutions in my answer: one for changing the XSD (1 and 3) and the other for changing the XML (2 and 4).

Comment: @zx485 I read your answer. It's not right. Perhaps you can make a file validate that way, but it won't be accepted by the CRA. The XSD files are fine and the XML needs to be majorly changed. Half the content that the XML file needs is missing. It should not start with <Return>. See https://www.canada.ca/en/revenue-agency/services/e-services/filing-information-returns-electronically-t4-t5-other-types-returns-overview/upcoming-year-t619.html. Perhaps you technically answered the question, but then the question is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is that your `<Return>` is supposed to be included inside a `<Submission>` as per https://www.canada.ca/en/revenue-agency/services/e-services/filing-information-returns-electronically-t4-t5-other-types-returns-overview/upcoming-year-t619.html.

When I followed that, my xml file validated against the schemas included in https://www.canada.ca/content/dam/cra-arc/serv-info/eservices/xmlschm1-20-5.zip

I didn't have to make any modifications to the XSD files like in the currently accepted answer.

The file you submit to the CRA should look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Submission xmlns:ccms="http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/xmlns/ccms/1-0-0" 
  xmlns:sdt="http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/xmlns/sdt/2-2-0" 
  xmlns:ols="http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/enov/ol/interfaces/efile/partnership/ols/1-0-1" 
  xmlns:ols1="http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/enov/ol/interfaces/efile/partnership/ols1/1-0-1" 
  xmlns:ols10="http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/enov/ol/interfaces/efile/partnership/ols10/1-0-1" 
  xmlns:ols100="http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/enov/ol/interfaces/efile/partnership/ols100/1-0-1" 
  xmlns:ols12="http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/enov/ol/interfaces/efile/partnership/ols12/1-0-1" 
  xmlns:ols125="http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/enov/ol/interfaces/efile/partnership/ols125/1-0-1" 
  xmlns:ols140="http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/enov/ol/interfaces/efile/partnership/ols140/1-0-1" 
  xmlns:ols141="http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/enov/ol/interfaces/efile/partnership/ols141/1-0-1" 
  xmlns:ols2="http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/enov/ol/interfaces/efile/partnership/ols2/1-0-1" 
  xmlns:ols5="http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/enov/ol/interfaces/efile/partnership/ols5/1-0-1" 
  xmlns:ols50="http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/enov/ol/interfaces/efile/partnership/ols50/1-0-1" 
  xmlns:ols52="http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/enov/ol/interfaces/efile/partnership/ols52/1-0-1" 
  xmlns:ols6="http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/enov/ol/interfaces/efile/partnership/ols6/1-0-1" 
  xmlns:ols8="http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/enov/ol/interfaces/efile/partnership/ols8/1-0-1" 
  xmlns:ols8-1="http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/enov/ol/interfaces/efile/partnership/ols8-1/1-0-1" 
  xmlns:ols9="http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/enov/ol/interfaces/efile/partnership/ols9/1-0-1" 
  xmlns:olsbr="http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/enov/ol/interfaces/efile/partnership/olsbr/1-0-1" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="layout-topologie.xsd">
  <T619>
    <sbmt_ref_id>00000001</sbmt_ref_id>
    <rpt_tcd>O</rpt_tcd>
    <trnmtr_nbr>MM555555</trnmtr_nbr>
    <trnmtr_tcd>1</trnmtr_tcd>
    <summ_cnt>1</summ_cnt>
    <lang_cd>E</lang_cd>
    <TRNMTR_NM>
      <l1_nm>CAREER COLLEGE</l1_nm>
    </TRNMTR_NM>
    <TRNMTR_ADDR>
      <addr_l1_txt>Address of School</addr_l1_txt>
      <cty_nm>ABBOTSFORD</cty_nm>
      <prov_cd>BC</prov_cd>
      <cntry_cd>CAN</cntry_cd>
      <pstl_cd>V2W3A9</pstl_cd>
    </TRNMTR_ADDR>
    <CNTC>
      <cntc_nm>JOHN LASTNAME</cntc_nm>
      <cntc_area_cd>604</cntc_area_cd>
      <cntc_phn_nbr>720-4037</cntc_phn_nbr>
      <cntc_email_area>john@careercollege.com</cntc_email_area>
    </CNTC>
  </T619>
  <Return>
    Your return from above goes here
  </Return>
</Submission>
```

Comment: yes I made the submission without T619 and it got rejected by CRA.